# How to uncollapse a list with coma separated columns in python?

Tags: python, list

I'm working in a code and I have a list like:

```
listA = (
    ['name1', 'A11,A12,A13', 'B11,B12,B13', 'C11,C12,C13'],
    ['name2', 'A21,A22', 'B21,B22', 'C21,C22'],
    ['name3', 'A31,A32,A33,A34,A35', 'B31,B32,B33,B34,B35', 'C31,C32,C33,C34,C35' ],
)
```

and I need to get:

```
listA = (
    ['name1', 'A11', 'B11', 'C11'],
    ['name1', 'A12', 'B12', 'C12'],
    ['name1', 'A13', 'B13', 'C13'],
    ['name2', 'A21', 'B21', 'C21'],
    ['name2', 'A22', 'B22', 'C22'],
    ['name3', 'A31', 'B31', 'C31'],
    ['name3', 'A32', 'B32', 'C32'],
    ['name3', 'A33', 'B33', 'C33'],
    ['name3', 'A34', 'B34', 'C34'],
    ['name3', 'A35', 'B35', 'C35'],
)
```

please help me, I'm staked.
Thanks for your time.

Comment: Are your sure the first line of `listA` is correct?  There seem to be to many quotes.

Comment: Is the 3rd item of the first line really separated in single items or is it just like the 2 other lines?

Comment: @Sven Marnach It wasn't correct. thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
list_b = []
for x in list_a:
    i = iter(x)
    name = next(i)
    list_b.extend((name,) + t for t in zip(*(y.split(",") for y in i)))
```

Answer (score 1):

Kinda ugly, but...

```
listB = []
for tup in listA:
  tmptup = []
  for elt in tup:
    splt = elt.split(',')
    for n in splt:
      tmptup.append(n)
  listB.append(tmptup)
```

Comment: You could just use tmptup.extend(elt.split(',')) to replace the inner loop and the line preceding it.

Comment: Totally! That would be way nicer.

Answer (score 1):

```
listA = tuple([name, a, b, c] for (name, aas, bbs, ccs) in listA
                              for (a, b, c) in zip(aas.split(','), bbs.split(','), ccs.split(',')))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
def uncollapse(L):
    temp = []
    answer = []
    for item in L:
        temp= [item[0]] + [i.split(',') for i in item]
        for i in range(len(temp[1])):
            answer.append([temp[0]] + [zip(*temp[1:])[i]])
    return answer
```

Tested and working

Comment: I get [['name3', ('name3', 'A31', 'B31', 'C31')]] :S. But thanks anyway.